# How can I make it so the text boxes in tkinter are created on a canvas and not on the window itself?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to make it so whenever you press the "+" button, it creates a text box on the canvas that is inside of the window. But, whenever I try to do that, it just puts it on the window itself and not on the canvas. Here is the code. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
from tkinter import *
from random import choice
root = Tk()
    


root.title("TBCITW")
root.geometry('340x800')
root.resizable (1,1)

canvasmain=Canvas(
    root,
    bg="#1c1c1c",
    width=340, 
    height=10000,)
canvasmain.place(x=-2, y=41,)
    
def plusentrymain():
    global textplus
    textplus=Entry(canvasmain).grid(padx=5, pady=5)
    

#Buttons
button1=Button(root, text=" + ", padx=2,command=plusentrymain)
button1.place(x=10, y=10)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: The _proper_ way to show widgets inside canvas is using `create_window()` method of canvas objects.

Comment: The text box is actually created inside canvas but the size of canvas is shrink to fit the text box. There is a black border around the text box which is the canvas.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the widget `canvasmain` to `root` in line 21. Outside of the function, I added an Entry.

Python is the rule. I altered the code to make it readable.

```
from tkinter import *
from random import choice


root = Tk()
root.title("TBCITW")
root.geometry('340x800')
root.resizable (1,1)

canvasmain=Canvas(
    root,
    bg="#1c1c1c",
    width=340, 
    height=10000,
    )

canvasmain.place(x=2, y=41,)
    
def plusentrymain():
    global textplus
    textplus=Entry(root)
    textplus.grid(padx=5, pady=5)
    

#Buttons
button1=Button(root, text=" + ", padx=2, command=plusentrymain)
button1.place(x=10, y=10)

#Entry
textplus=Entry(root)
textplus.grid(padx=5, pady=45)

root.mainloop()
```

Output:

Before click..

[image]

After click.

[image]

Comment: I could write another for spacing. But it takes a hard time. I'm uiisng Python 3.11.0rc2